# How can I put my div "downloads" always 70px below my image

Tags: html, css

Im trying to put my `<div id="downloads">` always 70px below my image, but Im not having sucess doing this.

If my text have a lot of words and has the height of my image, it is working fine.

But when my text is smaller, and dont have the height of my image, it is not working fine, my `<div id="downloads">` comes up too much and have 70px in relation to my paragraph. But I want in relation to my image.

Do you know how can I position my `<div id="downloads">` in relation to my image, to always have `margin-top:70px;` of my image?

This is my fiddle with what Im doing and what Im having:
http://jsfiddle.net/p95EN/2/

This is what Im looking for:

[image]

**My html:**

```
    <div class="modal">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <span id="date">date</span><br />
    <img class="img" src="uploads/news/image1.png"/>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer.</p>
    <div id="downloads">
        <h3>Downloads:</h3>
        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span>Back</span>
</div>
```

**My css:**

```
.modal
{   
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    background:#fff;
}

.modal .img 
{
    width:200px;
    height:220px; 
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:3px solid green;
    margin-top:15px;
}

.modal #date
{
    width:100%;
    color:#ccc;
    font-size:14px; 
    text-align:center;
    color:#7a7a7a;
}


.modal h2
{
    width:100%;
    color:green;
    font-size:23px; 
    text-align:center;

}

.modal p
{
    font-size: 17px;  
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:25px;
    word-spacing:-2px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:15px;
}

#downloads
{
    margin-top:70px;
}

#downloads h3
{
    color:#444;
}

.links 
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto; 
    display:table;
}


.links li
{
     text-align : left;
}

.links li a>i
{
     color:#444;
}


.links li a 
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    margin:0 auto; 
    margin-top:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing following Class within the CSS:

```
 #downloads { clear: both; text-align: center; display: block; width: auto; margin-top: 70px; }
```

Comment: Thank you Bhasyakarakulu, it worked perfectly with only clear:both

Comment: Well, I also need to float: left, but then my div is not centered and I needed it centered. Do you know how I can do it? Because Im using float:left, but I need also to center my div...

Comment: I know that I can use margin-left, but its not possible to align at center automatically?

Comment: #downloads {
            clear: both;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            width: auto;
            margin-top: 70px;
        }

Comment: Thanks Bhasyakarulu Kottakota, but like that, without float:left, my margin-top:70px dont works corretly!